# Cantor distribution

Tags: probability

For a random variable $X=2\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{X_n}{3^n}$, where $X_n$ 's are independent random variables taking value at $0$ and $1$ with equal probability. If $x$ can be expanded as $x=\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{c_{nx}}{3^n}$, where $c_{nx}\in \{0,1,2\}$. How to get $P(X\le x) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{c_{nx}}{2^n}$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: In some paper, they define a $N_x = \min \{c_{nx}: c_{nx} =1 \}$, so the cantor distribution can be expressed as $\frac{1}{2^{N_x}} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{N_x-1} \frac{c_{nx}}{2^n}$. I think this helps but I'm still confused about the detail. Since $2 X_n$ picking values only at $0$ and $2$,  the analysis on the first $N_x$ digits  should be easier.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be an issue with the problem statement: suppose $c_1 = 1$; then $P(X\leq x) = P(X_1=0) = \frac{1}{2}$ regardless of the other $c_k$s.

Comment: $c_1=1$ if and only if $x \in [1/3,2/3)$, now $X \leq x$ in general can occur even if $X_1=1$. For example if $x=4/9,X_1=1,X_2=0$ and the higher $X_n$ can do whatever, then $X \leq x$.